# How to get other JSON value using composition api v-model select box?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm studying composition API v-model.

I can get one value from JSON using below code. but I couldn't figure out other data. Could you teach me how to get multiple value from JSON?

[Runable live code link is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-composition-api-script-setup-example-forked-y2n5wl?file=/src/App.vue)

**Here is my current code**

```
<select v-model="pl1">
  <option v-for="pl1 in items" :key="pl1.id" 
 :value="pl1.name">{{ pl1.name }}  {{ pl1.price }}</option>
 </select>

<p>This is selected Product list NAME (Works fine)-> {{ pl1 }}</p>
<p>price This doesn't work -> {{ pl1 }}</p>

const items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'apple' , price: 100  },
    { id: 2, name: 'banana' , price: 80  },
];

const pl1 =ref('');//works fine
const pl1_price =ref('');

const form = reactive({
    'pl1': pl1,//works fine
    'pl1_price': pl1_price
})
const { errors, storeCompany } = useCompanies()
const saveCompany = async () => {
    await storeCompany({ ...form });
}
</script>
```

Comment: please add a minimal runnable demo link. such as a `codepen` link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for response. Sorry. I just add runnable demo link my question. Could you take a look please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a stripped down version of the solution

```js
 <template>
  <select v-model="id" @change="changeHandler">
    <option v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <p>name => {{ form.name }}</p>
  <p>price => {{ form.price }}</p>
</template>


<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "apple", price: 100 },
  { id: 2, name: "banana", price: 80 },
];

const id = ref(0);
const form = reactive({
  name: "",
  price: 0,
});

const changeHandler = () => {
  // Filter out selected item by id ✅
  const item = items.find((item) => id.value === item.id);
  form.name = item.name;
  form.price = item.price;
};
</script>
```

> live demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-composition-api-script-setup-reactive-ref-select-4r8v8y?file=/src/App.vue:0-691

Comment: Dear @xgqfrms Thank you very much.
I learned a lot from your code. I really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the value field... because you are passing pl1.name it will always already have a name.. but you can pass the entire object there ..

check this

```
 <template>
  <select v-model="pl1">
    <option v-for="pl1 in items" :key="pl1.id" :value="pl1">
      {{ pl1.name }} {{ pl1.price }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <p>Selected product: {{ pl1.name }}</p>
  <p>Selected product's price: {{ pl1.price }}</p>
</template>


<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "apple", price: 100 },
  { id: 2, name: "banana", price: 80 },
];

const pl1 = ref(""); //works fine
const pl1_price = ref("");

const form = reactive({
  pl1: pl1, //works fine
  pl1_price: pl1_price,
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's right, but the `form` doesn't work at all.  In your code, the variables "pl1_price" and "form" are both dead code.

Comment: see the answer above then :) from @gqfrms

Comment: Dear @Mr.P Thank you very much for helping me.
I appreciate your code and kind explanation.
I surprised there are different way to write code. Thank you so much.